# How to spawn future only if free worker is available

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

I am trying to send information extracted from lines of a big file to a process running on some server.

To speed this up, I would like to do this with some threads in parallel.

Using the Python 2.7 backport of [concurrent.futures](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) I tried this:

```
f = open("big_file")
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as e:
    for line in f:
        e.submit(send_line_function, line)
f.close()
```

However, this is problematic, because all futures get submitted instantly, so that my machine runs out of memory, because the complete file gets loaded into memory.

My question is, if there is an easy way to only submit a new future when a free worker is available.

Comment: It may be faster to use the [`os.sendfile`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.sendfile) function to send transfer the file over a socket.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that this example is a bit simplified... in reality I am posting information extracted from each line of the file to a JSON-REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over chunks of the file using

```
for chunk in zip(*[f]*chunksize):
```

(This is an application of the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), which collects items from the iterator `f` into groups of size `chunksize`. Note: This does not consume the entire file at once since `zip` returns an iterator in Python3.)

---

```
import concurrent.futures as CF
import itertools as IT
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='[%(asctime)s %(threadName)s] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S')

def worker(line):
    line = line.strip()
    logger.info(line)

chunksize = 1024
with CF.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor, open("big_file") as f:
    for chunk in zip(*[f]*chunksize):
        futures = [executor.submit(worker, line) for line in chunk]
        # wait for these futures to complete before processing another chunk
        CF.wait(futures)
```

---

Now, in the comments you rightly point out that this is not optimal. 
There could be some worker which takes a long time, and holds up a whole chunk of jobs.

Usually, if each call to worker takes roughly the same amount of time then this is not a big deal. However, here is a way to advance the filehandle on-demand. It uses a `threading.Condition` to notify the `sprinkler` to advance the filehandle.

```
import logging
import threading
import Queue

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='[%(asctime)s %(threadName)s] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
SENTINEL = object()

def worker(cond, queue):
    for line in iter(queue.get, SENTINEL):
        line = line.strip()
        logger.info(line)
        with cond:
            cond.notify()
            logger.info('notify')

def sprinkler(cond, queue, num_workers):
    with open("big_file") as f:
        for line in f:
            logger.info('advancing filehandle') 
            with cond:
                queue.put(line)
                logger.info('waiting')
                cond.wait()
        for _ in range(num_workers):
            queue.put(SENTINEL)

num_workers = 4
cond = threading.Condition()
queue = Queue.Queue()
t = threading.Thread(target=sprinkler, args=[cond, queue, num_workers])
t.start()

threads = [threading.Thread(target=worker, args=[cond, queue])]
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: I like where this is going but it suffers from the original problem. The main thread still tries to queue the entier file. How about a single return queue where each thread posts a 'done' message. The main thread could put, say, 16 items on the queue and then only add items as it gets 'done' messages.

Comment: Okay, in that case you could process the file in chunks using `for chunk in IT.izip(*[f]*chunksize)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I haven't been able to test this yet, but it might speed things up for me indeed. However, it is not an optimal solution, because as far as I can see all futures in the chunk have to finish before a new chunk gets dispatched (which might lead to idle workers). Please also note that I'm using Python 2.7 and the backport of concurrent.futures, so in this case one probably has to use `izip`.

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed reply! The second approach seems to solve the problem in a more optimal way, however it is also quite bulky. When posting the question I was hoping that there was a more compact/pythonic solution without using queues etc., like your first one was. So I'll leave the question opened a few more days to see if there is another way to approach this, for now I'll use your first suggestion, as in my case the requests should take roughly the same amount of time indeed, so thanks again.